# Why HTML5 has separate TAG for header,nav,article?

Tags: html, information-retrieval, text-mining

Why exactly HTML 5 has provided separate tag's for header , articles. Is it to give a readable/understandable for programmers or is WEB becoming more suitable to Information retrieval. I mean we have unstructured data in html pages too and traditional **table** and **div** are not that informative for a automatic program to figure out that what is header and what is content. It seems more semantically informative tags will be useful in the future.

Comment: Have a look at http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/ for a discussion of sectioning elements and a flowchart to assist in deciding which ones to use.

Answer (score 0):

It is just semantics.

For who?

1. The browser: Browsers can zoom in now to the `article`. They can skip `nav` since it is less relevant (or show extra options when printing);
2. Search engines: analyze the content better;
3. Developer: you know better where you are talking / coding about.

Technically there is no difference between `nav`, `article` and `div`.